# How to set flink parallelism in pure java (IDEA)

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using following scala code to run my flink streaming job

```
val mystream = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    mystream.addSource(new mySource(params))
      .map(new myMap(params))
      .addSink(new mySink(params)).setParallelism(1)
    mystream.setParallelism(1)
    mystream.execute("My Streaming")
```

when I use `flink run -p 1`, the parallelism is 1(do not know whether -p works or the code works). when I use pure java to run, (in IDEA I suppose it runs in pure java), the parallelism is usually 5, which shows my code does not work. How to control it?

---

as top answer suggested, following code also does not work, still has parellelism of 5.

```
val mystream = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    mystream.addSource(new mySource(params))
      .map(new myMap(params))
      .addSink(new mySink(params))
    mystream.setParallelism(1)
    mystream.execute("My Streaming")
```

Comment: Don't forget to chain your topology. If you don't want to chain, you need to update `mystream = mystream.setParallelism(1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the default parallelism on the environment.

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setParallelism(1)
env.addSource(...)
```

Using `.addSink(new mySink(params)).setParallelism(1)` overrides that default parallelism for the specific operator.

Comment: so only use `env.setParallelism(1)` and remove `.addSink(new mySink(params)).setParallelism(1)` would work? I tried, still 5 instances...

Comment: Can you please update your code in the question, it's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your code and respective logs.